# how can i install shineOn in Delphiprism?

Tags: delphi, prism, delphi-prism, oxygene

how can i install shineOn in Delphiprism?
I download ShineOn package for useing old's delphi functions such as inttostr and ...
but i can istall or add them in my delphi area.
Please help me.
Regards

Answer (score 1):

Download the zip from: http://code.remobjects.com/p/shineon/downloads/

In it you'll fine a two dlls, right click your projects 'References' tab, and press 'Add Reference', select the dlls you want (probably rtl, vcl). Then add 
ShineOn.Rtl

or

ShineOn.Vcl

to your uses list.